# Show arrow on non selectable nodes

Tags: asp.net, menu

I have a databound ASP.net menu with the following databindings

```
<DataBindings>
<asp:MenuItemBinding TextField="title" ToolTipField="description" NavigateUrlField="url" SelectableField="AsLink"  />
</DataBindings>
```

Now any node which becomes non selectable also loses its arrow, even if it has children

Why is that and how can we remedy this?

I have seen some suggestions to use `StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage`.

Neither should it, as its purpose is according to msdn

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the built-in image is displayed to indicate that a static menu item has a submenu

And my issue is equally with static and dynamic nodes, in case of non-selectability

I'm using .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Menu control adds a style on the static menu item anchor(`<a>`) element (`style="cursor: text"`) when it is not selectable so you need to manully change it.

1. Change the Css for your Static Menu Style to make it easy to find the right anchor elements:

   ```
      <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="StaticMenuHover" />
   ```
2. Add a Jquery script to the end of the page to change the pointer for the menu items:

   ```
   //Grab all Static Menu anchors elements with an href of '#'(Non active links)

   $(".StaticMenuHover a[href='#']").css("cursor","pointer");
   ```